# Google Analytics Management API v4(ua) > Google Analytics Admin API v1(ga4) migration is in progress

Tags: google-analytics-api

Right now, I'm
Google Analytics Management API v4(ua) > Google Analytics Admin API v1(ga4) migration is in progress.

In the case of the existing v4, there was an example of a Java test code called Hello Analytics Reporting in Google's official document, and we were able to proceed without much difficulty.

However, v1 can't find the example code no matter how hard it looks.
(I found a page related to migration, but it was only the code for the request.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/reporting-ua-to-ga4?hl=ko)

Where can I find the information?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

For example in JAVA:

```
            GoogleCredentials credentials =
                            GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(your credentialsJson Path));
        
                    BetaAnalyticsDataSettings betaAnalyticsDataSettings =
                            BetaAnalyticsDataSettings.newBuilder()
                            .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                            .build();    
  
        
                    try (BetaAnalyticsDataClient analyticsData =
                            BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(betaAnalyticsDataSettings)) {
                         
                        int offset=0;
                        int limit=100000;
            RunReportRequest request =
                        RunReportRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setProperty("properties/" + your propertyId)
         
                        .addDateRanges(DateRange.newBuilder().setStartDate(your statr date).setEndDate(your end date))
        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("date")) 
                        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("eventName"))
        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("eventCount"))
                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("eventsPerSession"))
                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("eventValue"))
                        .setOffset(offset)
                        .setLimit(limit)
                        .build();
        RunReportResponse response = analyticsData.runReport(request);

}
```